# Binding Events rather than using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been told its better to bind events to elements rather than having `onclick`s with functions everywhere. I agree with this as it devolves more from the HTML which means cleaner and easier to debug code.

But I am having trouble doing this! I loop through some data with PHP (see below) and I currently use onclick to call a function. How can I bind this onclick event to many elements using JQuery.

```
<?php foreach($main_tags as $key=>$value){ ?>
<li>
    <a id="<?php echo $key; ?>" href="#" onclick="tag_search('<?php echo $key; ?>'); return false;">
    <?php echo $key; ?>
        <span class="num-active">
            <?php echo $value; ?>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Thanks all for any help

Comment: I think you should provide a fall-back solution when JavaScript is turned off. `href="#"` leads to nothing.

Comment: @Marcel - I don't want any users who do not have JS to even bother visiting my site. A bit cruel, but it must be so because of the nature of this app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul id="container">
<?php foreach($main_tags as $key=>$value){ ?>
<li>
    <a href="#" key="<?php echo $key;?>">
    <?php echo $key; ?>
        <span class="num-active">
            <?php echo $value; ?>
        </span>
    </a>
</li>
<?php } ?> 
</div>
<script>
$(function() {

function tag_search(){};

$('#container a').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
tag_search.call( this, $(this).attr('key') );
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: Ah I see! I was concentrating on doing something within the loop but fearing that the JS code will also be duplicated. But I can just use a broad selector! Thank you meder! :)

Comment: To make it better suited to XHTML standards, I would change the attribute `key` to `data-key`, and then change the corresponding JS from `$(this).attr('key')` to `$(this).attr('data-key')`.

Comment: @Matt - Godamn, I knew someone was gonna mention that sooner or later. Name it as you wish, same concept though.

Answer (score 1):

You can [iterate over a group of divs or lis or whatever with JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

The code below doesn't show the php, and it uses alerts to show what's going on with the JQery... I commented what would be the actual code.... hope it helps. Like this you don't have to worry about ids, since the order of items is what's important. You could of course leave the ids in.

Edit - added how to handle custom keys

**Case 1: Numerical keys**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Binding events</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JQUERY-PATH/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">  
                        // When the page is ready ==================================================
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('li').each(function(index) 
                {
                    // The line below would read something like:
                    // $(this).click( function () {tag_search(index)});
                    $(this).click( function() { alert("This would trigger => tag_search(" + index + ")")});                    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        The php goes into the unordered list:
        <ul>
            <li>zero</li>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
            <li>five</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Case 2: Custom keys of your choice**

If you have keys that are all numbers, you may want to stick an arbitrary letter in front, so that it validates for id or class names.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Binding events</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">  
            // When the page is ready ==================================================
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $('li').each(function(index) 
                {
                    // The line below would read something like:
                    // $(this).click( function () {tag_search($(this).attr('id'))});
                    $(this).click( function() { alert("This would trigger => tag_search(" + $(this).attr('id') + ")")});                    
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        The php goes into the unordered list:
        The custom keys are placed in ids or classes:
        <ul>
            <li id="Roger">zero</li>
            <li id="Dodger">one</li>
            <li id="23884">two</li>
            <li id="Fubar">three</li>
            <li id="Gungho">four</li>
            <li id="Burlap">five</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is an interesting method. So the benefit looks like PHP will do a bit less work and JQuery will be given some responsibility to do some work. Meaning slightly faster page loads? Is this similar to what meder's code is doing?

Comment: That's why I asked what `key` was - I wasnt sure if it was just `0,1,2` or custom keys.

Comment: @Meder - no key is not incremental, its an id specific to that tag. It can be 123, 34, 456. No order. Btw, I didn't see your comment about what `key` was.

Comment: You can also use this sort of method for custom keys... I added in case 2 to show how.

Comment: @Abs - ok, then my solution should be ideal. Peter's second part is the same as my original solution except semantically its better to keep it as its own attribute because class can have multiple values.